# Spring mongoDB auditing get the source data to update on the table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I am trying to implement delete auditing in spring data with MongoDB.I have the below entity model

```
@Document("Product")
@FieldNameConstants
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product extends OptimisticLock<Integer>{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field("name")
    @TextIndexed
    private String name;
    @Field("price")
    private float price;
    @Field("description")
    @TextIndexed(weight = 2)
    private String description;
}
```

When I tried to hook the life cycle event and get the source. I am able to get the value for only Id and version which is from the OptimisticLock.

```
@Override
    public void onAfterDelete(AfterDeleteEvent<Object> event) {
        LOG.info("On After delete inserting the record to the Delete and update collection");
        Object obj = event.getSource();
        DeleteUpdateAudit deleteUpdateAudit = new DeleteUpdateAudit(obj, DatabaseAction.DELETE);
        this.mongoTemplate.insert(deleteUpdateAudit);
    }
```

[image]

The reason for that is I need to trace what item has been deleted instead of Id and version, because the data will be deleted, so what is the use of ID.

Comment: How about using BeforeDeleteEvent instead of AfterDeleteEvent?

Comment: How do we handle if actual delete operation fails and BeforeDeleteEvent successful? Even BeforeDeleteEvent given me a same result as after, same item I can see in the source

Comment: Well, just an idea: you could add a flag `committed` to the DeleteUpdateAudit entity. You would put DeleteUpdateAudit to the DB on BeforeDeleteEvent and set the flag on AfterDeleteEvent.

Comment: That is okay, I can implement, but I am not able to get all the model data even in the BeforeDeleteEvent or AfterDeleteEvent, How do I get all the values from the model